# Excel 2013: #REF error with formula

Tags: excel-formula

Trying to get an average of cells that fit under certain criteria. Getting a #REF error with this formula. Was wondering if anyone could give it a look? Not sure what is wrong with it.

```
=(AVERAGE(INDEX('2011_2016 Well 
Data'!$H$2:$H$181,MATCH(Summary!C1,'2011_2016 Well 
Data'!$E$2:$E$181,0)&MATCH(Summary!$D$2,'2011_2016 Well 
Data'!$F$2:$F$181,0)&MATCH(Summary!$B$4,'2011_2016 Well 
Data'!$G$2:$G$181,0)&MATCH(Summary!$A$3,'2011_2016 Well 
Data'!$C$2:$C$181,0))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MATCH&MATCH&MATCH` is not a thing in Excel, at least not in the way you are trying to implement it.

I think what you are looking for is the `AVERAGEIFS` formula, which allows you to average based on multiple criteria.

This should do the trick, with the caveat that I don't know what you data looks like and I'm making the following assumptions based on the formula you have provided.

'2011_2016 Well Data'!$H$2:$H$181 is the range with the numbers you want to average

```
Criteria      Looked for in this range
Summary!C1    '2011_2016 Well Data'!$E$2:$E$181
Summary!$D$2  '2011_2016 Well Data'!$F$2:$F$181
Summary!$B$4  '2011_2016 Well Data'!$G$2:$G$181
Summary!$A$3  '2011_2016 Well Data'!$C$2:$C$181
```

Here is the formula

```
=AVERAGEIFS('2011_2016 Well Data'!$H$2:$H$181,'2011_2016 Well Data'!$E$2:$E$181,Summary!C1,'2011_2016 Well Data'!$F$2:$F$181,Summary!$D$2,'2011_2016 Well Data'!$G$2:$G$181,Summary!$B$4,'2011_2016 Well Data'!$C$2:$C$181,Summary!$A$3)
```

Or in an easier to read view

```
=AVERAGEIFS('2011_2016 Well Data'!$H$2:$H$181,
    '2011_2016 Well Data'!$E$2:$E$181, Summary!C1,
    '2011_2016 Well Data'!$F$2:$F$181, Summary!$D$2,
    '2011_2016 Well Data'!$G$2:$G$181, Summary!$B$4,
    '2011_2016 Well Data'!$C$2:$C$181, Summary!$A$3)
```